# unable to load java class from jar file file

Tags: java, jar

My jar is in Class Path and i want to load a class from jar file i am trying to load it like blow,

```
Class cls = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(<package-name>.<class-name>);
```

but I am getting

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.perennial.genericsync.xero.SyncAdaptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

please help me how can i load class file from jar. jar is already there in Class Path. is it say that System Loader can not load class from jar?

how can I load java class? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(name)` if your jar is in classpath.

Comment: WC. Please mark the answer as correct if it has solved your problem. Thanks.